# Python for controlling Application from CLI

Tags: python

I have an application, which allows both by GUI and CLI. Is there any option to make use of this CLI commands using python, so that i can automate the set of process for that application(i.e. replace the set of work with single click)

Comment: "Is there any option....?" The answer is probably "yes", but the question is vague. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: instead of opening an application and doing some brainless work, what is the option (Eg: which python library / how to write a python script) , so that by double clicking on .exe file it should do all those process in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
from subprocess import check_output

# check_output returns the output of the command
# note: date is a unix command, try something else if on windows
result = check_output('date', encoding='utf8')

print(result)
```